# Google spreadsheet: How to add notification rule (in script)

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to create script for the next task:

- select range in spreadsheet
- click special item in menu (no prob with that part)
- as a result: this range automatically added as new notification rule (see in menu Tools)

I've checked spreadsheet classes (Range, Sheet, Spreadsheet, SpreadsheetApp), and search it in inet - no results so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible now, because, as you wrote, there is no GAS functionality to manage the notification rules. Also I have not found any feature request on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) asking this functionality. Please submit a new feature request to the issue tracker to help Google to understand which features are required for the users.

Comment: Ok. I've added it as an [enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1808). Please vote, if anybody interested in it also.

Comment: @yso Greetings from the future! I starred your request but it's *still* not available.